# Having problems compiling shaka player

Tags: javascript, python, mpeg-dash, shaka

```
[WARNING] No changes detected, skipping. Use --force to override.
[INFO] Generating Closure dependencies...
[INFO] Linting JavaScript...
[ERROR] *** A required dependency is missing: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
```

I have followed the instructions given by the shaka-player https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/tutorial-welcome.html but it does not work and throws the above error.

Comment: does `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE` exist? Did you also install Git, Python, JRE as documented in `Prerequisites` at the very top of the page you linked to?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the following:
- Git version 2.35.1.windows.2
- Node v18.17.1
- Python 3.10.4
- Java Runtime Environment v21

Comment: I'll ask the first part again, does `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE` exist?

Comment: Sorry about that, yes it does exist and I'm using Node v18.17.1

Comment: so `A required dependency is missing` is a bug in whatever output that is - which step spews that output?

Comment: The step that where it asks to compile the library:
`python build/all.py`

Comment: are you running this in a command prompt or  powershell?

Comment: I'm using Git Bash on windows

Comment: I wonder if that's confusing the compiler script

Comment: Do you mean using Git Bash is confusing the compiler script?!

Comment: that's exactly what I suggested

Comment: No, I don't think it has anything to do with Git Bash, I just tried using PowerShell and I still get exactly the same error.

Comment: what about CMD? I know the builder has to treat windows specially, so, the numpty who wrote shaka may be lazy

Comment: CMD is giving the same error

Comment: check out the issues on shaka github - https://github.com/shaka-project/shaka-player/issues/4937 no solution, but known issue

Comment:  Not sure if it because of the numpty who wrote shaka or because of my system/computer!

Comment: `I was able to get past the error by simply moving the repo folder to a higher directory` - they put the repo in the root of C: drive - not sure you have to be that drastic, but how long is the path to your copy of the repo?

Comment: They were definitely lazy when reporting errors ... the actual error is not that node is missing, it's that running the command produces an error (`[WinError 206] The filename or extension is too long`) which is never output, giving misleading information :p

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Sorry didn't see your other comment earlier. My path to the repo is: `C:\Users\Haidari\Desktop\Libs\shaka-player`

Comment: try moving your repo "higher" (i.e. so the path is shorter) - that path shouldn't be too long if you ask me, but try moving it anyway - maybe try `C:\Users\Haidari\shaka-player` - if that fails `C:\shaka-player` :p

Comment: Ok, I've moved it to `C:\Users\Haidari` and the old error is gone but now I'm getting a new error: `ESLint couldn't find the plugin "eslint-plugin-shaka-rules". (The package "eslint-plugin-shaka-rules" was not found when loaded as a Node module from the directory "C:\Users\Haidari\shaka-player".) It's likely that the plugin isn't installed correctly. Try reinstalling by running the following: npm install eslint-plugin-shaka-rules@latest --save-dev
 The plugin "eslint-plugin-shaka-rules" was referenced from the config file in "--config".
`

Comment: so, did you `npm install eslint-plugin-shaka-rules@latest --save-dev`?

Comment: When I run the command `npm install eslint-plugin-shaka-rules@latest --save-dev` to install the required node module, it throws another error: `npm ERR! Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Comment: *Delete node_modules/eslint-plugin-shaka-rules and run npm install* - from [this issue](https://github.com/shaka-project/shaka-player/issues/3551) (which is related to the first issue you got too, they moved the repo, and symlinks were broken) - personally, I'd delete the whole node_modules folder, then run `npm install` so everything is fresh

Comment: any further problems, I'd suggest you look in https://github.com/shaka-project/shaka-player/issues (search in both open and closed issues) - seems lots of people have lots of problems with building shaka, but they are usually solved

Comment: I just googled and found another way to get the compiled shaka-player, I can get it from a cdn, for example: [https://cdnjs.com/libraries/shaka-player](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/shaka-player). Thank you so much for your time and your help.

Comment: As you suggested deleting **node_modules** directory and running `npm install` solved the errors. Thank you for your help again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to build Shaka Player that was located in my `C:\Users\<my-name>\Downloads` folder.
I move it to `C:` and that's it. Problem solved.